# Az Copy Scheduled Task Created but not executing script

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler, azcopy, azure-service-principal

I am using a powershell script that will read in a service principal and use it to run azcopy sync:

```
$StorageAccountName = 'nkstgacct'
$ContainerName = 'netangularproject'

$StorageURL = 'https://' + $StorageAccountName + '.blob.core.windows.net/' + $ContainerName

$LocalPath = <source path>

$TenantID = ''
$AppID = ''
$Password = ''

$env:AZCOPY_SPA_CLIENT_SECRET = $Password


.\azcopy login --service-principal --application-id $AppID --tenant-id $TenantID


.\azcopy sync $LocalPath $StorageURL --recursive=true
```

From there, I add the script file into a windows scheduled task command to run every 5 min:

```
schtasks /CREATE /SC minute /MO 5 /TN "AzCopy Script 2" /TR C:\Users\nk\Documents\AzCopy\Windows\azcopyAutomatedTest.ps1
```

The windows scheduled task gets created but when it runs, it does not actually run the script. I've checked my storage account every-time the task runs and do not see it updated. I've also changed the file to .bat and .exe and have not seen it run as expected.

Comment: (Assuming typo) I also see that `$StorageAccountName` is not defined

Comment: yes it is defined sorry i forgot to paste that part

Answer (score 1):

The reason this wasn't running the script was because I did not include the path to the az copy folder in the script.

so I just added the az copy command path right before the:

```
$env:AZCOPY_SPA_CLIENT_SECRET = $Password
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have 3 things in place.

First you have to execute the script with `powershell.exe` the default application for opening `.ps1` files is notepad:

```
powershell.exe -file "C:\Users\nk\Documents\AzCopy\Windows\azcopyAutomatedTest.ps1"
```

Second, you have to set the [Execution Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies) from the default `RemoteSigned` to either `ByPass` or `Unrestricted`:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass
```

e.g.

```
schtasks /CREATE /SC minute /MO 5 /TN "AzCopy Script 2" /TR 'powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File "C:\Users\nk\Documents\AzCopy\Windows\azcopyAutomatedTest.ps1"'
```

Third, when you are running the powershell script as a scheduled job, it starts up in the `"C:\Windows\system32"` folder (Note: This also happens when you specify the "Start in" directory). So you have to have all your paths be Fully Qualified.

Comment: Hmm that did not work. I am still not seeing it do what it needs to.